# Compare Values inside array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am a newcomer in Php.
Given below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"tranc":["2"],"report":["2"],"company":["2"],"facilities":["2"],"area":["1"],"zone":["2"]}
    [1] => {"tranc":["2"],"report":["2"],"company":["1"],"facilities":["1"],"area":["1"],"zone":["2"]}
)
```

I need to compare Arry[0] and Array[1] and get field of  value "1" and store in an array .something this

```
{"tranc":["2"],"report":["2"],"company":["1"],"facilities":["1"],"area":["1"],"zone":["2"]}
```

Comment: Above array definition will throw syntax error. You should provide right data so that we can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the purpose of comparing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
'{"tranc":["2"],"report":["2"],"company":["2"],"facilities":["2"],"area":["1"],"zone":["2"]}',
'{"tranc":["2"],"report":["2"],"company":["1"],"facilities":["1"],"area":["1"],"zone":["2"]}',
    );

var_dump($array[1]); // will have the row you want i.e row with key = 1 
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
var_dump(json_decode($array[1])); // will have the object decoded from the json string.
```